# Android image button scaling / dimensions

Tags: java, android

Currently in the process of assigning images to the main menu to make it more aesthetic, however when assigning images to buttons how do we know what the correct resolution , aspect ratio or dpi is

For the background I know we can use 9 patch images, or provide the various dpi sizes. For an image button, what would be considered the best bet

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Covert your images accordingly into hpdi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi using image resizer and put them in all drawable folders. and for image buttons to set icons use src attribute  so icons will be set properly in center.